# Can't move objects with Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm designing a PCB with Altium 14 composed by 4 SMT headers (2 on top, rest on bottom) but everytime I try to move them it puts the cursor on coordinates -4699.664,49086.331 (way, way far from my design) and I have no idea why is that happening, so I can't move the objects.

Do you know why this is happening or at least know another way to move the object?

Comment: Did you design the footprints yourself or are they from a standard library?

Comment: Thanks for answering that, it made look at my footprints and I've realised that I forgot to set the origin. It's solved now :)

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected :)

Comment: You got the solution so maybe an answer would be great too. :) Just to see that it is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @brhans comment I've realised that I didn't set the origin on my original footprints. After fixing that everything is fine now